# ruby require command not loading correctly

Tags: ruby, osx-yosemite

First post, "Hello World"

I am working through the lynda videos on Ruby and am just getting to the part of requiring content from .rb files in irb. An example patch we made is named contact_info.rb and from irb I am trying to require that file. When executed it comes back with the attached below.

Some light googling made it seem like this is maybe a yosemite issue (running 10.10.3.), but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

Thanks all

```
irb(main):006:0> require contact_info.rb
LoadError: cannot load such file -- contact_info.rb
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from (irb):6
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in '<main>'
```

Comment: `require './contact_info.rb'` -- giving a relative path to `require` will only search your include directories. A "relative path", in this case, means one which does not being with `/` or `.`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Both require './contact_info.rb' and require_relative 'contact_info' worked since I was in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `require_relative 'contact_info'`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is in your current directory, type this in your command line:

```
irb -r './contact_info.rb'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that with any `require` statement, you omit the file extension:

```
require 'contact_info'
```

When you `require` a file, ruby only looks in certain directories on your computer for the file.  You can see which directories those are by running the following code:

```
p $LOAD_PATH
```

`In ruby 1.8.7`, the `$LOAD_PATH` array included `"."`, or the current directory, which means your code would have worked. But, including the current directory in $LOAD_PATH was deemed a security risk, so now you have to do something different:

1) One option is to use a `relative path` for the file you specify in the require statement:

```
require './contact_info'
```

The path is relative to the `current directory`.  That works fine if you have this structure:

```
/some/dir/
    your_prog.rb
    contact_info.rb
```

***And*** you switch directories to `/some/dir` and then run `your_prog.rb`:

```
~$ cd /some/dir
/some/dir$ ruby my_prog.rb
```

The require statement works--no problems. However, what if you do this:

```
/some/dir$ cd ..
/some$ ruby ./dir/your_prog.rb
```

Now, the current directory is `/some`, and `require './contact_info'` tells ruby to look in the `/some` directory for `contact_info.rb`--but it isn't there, so you will get the error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- ./contact_info.rb (LoadError)
```

2) To cure that problem, ruby added `require_relative`.  Paths specified with `require_relative` are relative to the location of ***the file*** that contains the `require_relative` statement.  As a result, the statement:

```
#your_prog.rb:
require_relative './contact_info'
```

...will look in the directory containing `your_prog.rb` for the file `contact_info.rb`. Now, doing this:

```
/some$ ruby ./dir/your_prog.rb
```

will work fine.  And in fact, in the `require_relative` you don't even have to write the `./` in the path:

```
#your_prog.rb:
require_relative 'contact_info'  #Look for contact_info.rb in the same
                                 #directory that contains this file

require_relative '../contact_info'  #Look for contact_info.rb one directory
                                    #above the directory that contains this file
```

> I am working through the lynda videos on Ruby and am just getting to
>   the part of requiring content from .rb files in irb.

In my opinion, it's not a good idea to use irb for much of anything. A better option is to create a couple of files called 1.rb, 2.rb, 3.rb, and do your coding in those files.